# When i try to generate Excel Report using PHP, values not getting generated,

Tags: php, excel, report

When i try to generate Excel Report using PHP, values not getting generated, I need to loop the mysqli_stmt_bind_result to excel file using while fetch

```
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($setRec, $emp_no, $emp_name, $designation, $location, $attend_date);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($setRec);
    $resultCheck2 = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($setRec);
    echo "result num_rowsss = $resultCheck2 \n";
            
    // $setRec = mysqli_query($link, $setSql);
    
    $columnHeader = '';
    $columnHeader = "Emp No" . "\t" . "Emp Name" . "\t" . "Designation" . "\t" . "Location" . "\t" . "Date" . "\t" . "Attendance" . "\t" . "Over Time" . "\t". "Remarks" . "\t";
    
    $setData = '';
    
    while ($rec = mysqli_stmt_fetch($setRec)) {
        $rowData = '';
        foreach ($rec as $value) {
            $value = '"' . $value . '"' . "\t";
            $rowData .= $value;
        }
        $setData .= trim($rowData) . "\n";
    }
    
    $filename = "Attendance_Reoprt.xls";
    $FN = $pdate.'_'.$filename;
    
    header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$FN.xls");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    
    echo ucwords($columnHeader) . "\n" . $setData . "\n";
    
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

Comment: I have issues in this code ($rec = mysqli_stmt_fetch($setRec))

Comment: i suggest you to use PHPSpreadsheet, is simple to use and ready to use.

Comment: I even tried JAVA Script to take the inner HTML to the excel but the select button also gets printed on the excel report.

Comment: please provide the content of `$setRec`

Comment: Amacado: $setRec = mysqli_prepare($link, $setSql);
                  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($setRec, "s", $userlocation);
             mysqli_stmt_execute($setRec);
             mysqli_stmt_bind_result($setRec, $emp_no, $emp_name, $designation, $location, $attend_date);
             mysqli_stmt_store_result($setRec);